# PHPUnit does not generate HTML output in PhpStorm for Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, phpunit, phpstorm

When I write PHPUnit tests for my Drupal 9 site there are no HTML output files as descriped here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/automated-testing/phpunit-in-drupal/phpunit-browser-test-tutorial

The `phpunit.xml` is configured with

```
<env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="/Users/[myusername]/[path_to_my_webroot]/web/sites/simpletest/browser_output">
```

The attribute `printerClass="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter"` is set.

Xdebug and PHPUnit both run in PhpStorm without further problems.

I debugged the core code and found that the `setUpHtmlOutput()` in `HtmlOutputPrinterTrait.php` is never called, therefore the `BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` is never set and the `initBrowserOutputFile()` in `BrowserHtmlDebugTrait.php` does not render anything.

Does anybody know how to activate the HTML output?

Comment: How do you run your tests? Using Run/Debug buttons in PhpStorm? Or outside / in the terminal? The thing is: PhpStorm uses own Output Printer (TeamCity one) -- that's how it tracks the test progress / sees the results. Check the command that PhpStorm runs (Console tab), it should have the printer parameter specified there. I believe this most likely will overwrite any output printers specified in the config file. *This comment is about interaction with PhpStorm. Cannot suggest why it may not work if you run this in terminal.*

Comment: Yes, I run tests directly in PHPStorm. And you are right, --teamcity is part of the command  PHPstorm uses. If I call the same command without the --teamcity option the parts of the code mentioned above become active, they seem indeed to be overwritten. I found no option to remove this parameter. So it seems that I have to choose between the PHPstorm-integration of the tests (which is quite comfortable) or the rendered browser output files? Or is there a way to let teamcity create the browser output for me?

Comment: I'm not using Drupal or PHPUnit Browser tests so cannot help here (what config is needed). I may only suggest to run your tests manually when you need that "HTML output" (e.g. in built-in terminal .. or create a External Tools for this so it can be easily invoked in PhpStorm) and use PhpStorm interface for the routine usage/debug/etc.

Comment: Thank you - maybe that would be good workaround. If somebody knows how to force PHPstorm to not show this behaviour I am open for suggestions :-)